# Counting cells using Excel VBA which are a result of a vlookup statement

Tags: vba, excel, count, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet on one sheet with the values in column C being generated using the results of a vlookup statement, from a value which I enter in column A.

I need to be able to count the number of cells in column C up to a maximum of 51 rows (from row 1 to row 51) which have a value in them, not including errors, after I have entered all my values in column A.

Oh - by the way, each time I do the count there will be a different number of rows used.

I've tried using:

```
ccc = Range("C:C").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

but this only counts the first line which is my header row.

Sorry if there is already an answer out there, but I've been looking for quite a while and can't find anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this without VBA, but you could try:

```
sub testy()
dim myRange as range
dim numRows as long

Set myRange = Range("C:C")
numRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(myRange) - _
myRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).Count

end sub
```

Your code is not working because `xlCellTypeConstants` is specifically telling it to count only constant values, ignoring formulas calculated values.

Comment: You're right, I have made the edit. Now, I don't have excel on this PC, so maybe he could count with `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas - xlErrors)`. I've never tried a substract operator there, only addition - maybe it'd work.

Comment: That's what I get for answering questions on a computer without Excel installed, haha.

Comment: But you will still have to subtract 1 for the header (because it will be included in the CountA but not in the SpecialCells.  (I'll add my +1 now - the OP can work out how to subtract one even if you don't edit the answer any further.)

Comment: That's what you get for listening to me!!

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

The worksheet function `CountA` counts only cells with values:

```
=CountA(C1:C51)
```

We can call any worksheet function from VBA with the WorksheetFunction function:

```
dim c as integer
c = WorksheetFunction.CountA([C1:C51])
```

---

`CountIf` can be used to skip errors:

```
Skip errors with:  `=COUNTIF(D5:D9,">0")`
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to count cells that have no errors.
Replace your vlookup by the below formula. So all errors will be replaced by "NOT FOUND" Text

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,A1:B3,2,FALSE), "NOT FOUND")
```

Then add this to find the number of cells that are non blank and non erroneous

```
=COUNTA(D:D) - COUNTIF(D:D,"NOT FOUND")
```

Assumptions:-

A:B Source Range

C Lookup Column

D the vlookup function is in this coulmn

For VBA

```
cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(D:D) - Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(D:D, "NOT FOUND")
```